# cakephp3- controller could not be found

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm learning cakephp 3 framework. Its better to say I'm pretty much new at this.

I'm trying to make a plugin.
I baked a plugin like this `bin/cake bake plugin myFirstPlugin`
Then I baked a controller for this plugin using

`bin/cake bake controller --plugin myFirstPlugin test`

So inside my plugin's controller, I defined a function which does nothing other than outputting a message.

This is my plugin's controller

```
<?php
namespace myFirstPlugin\Controller;

use myFirstPlugin\Controller\AppController;

class testController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $msg = 'test';
        $this->set(compact('msg'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['msg']);
    }
}
?>
```

and in my application's route (not in plugin's route) I wrote this:

```
Router::scope('/myFirstPlugin/index', function (RouteBuilder $routes){  
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'test', 'action' => 'index']);
});
```

So, when I try to call this using the below url

```
http://localhost/myApplication/myFirstPlugin/index
```

I got this error:

```
Error: testController could not be found.
Error: Create the class testController below in file: src\Controller\testController.php
```

Why am I getting such an error even  though I created a controller. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest that you switch to following the naming [**conventions**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html), that is, classes (and class files) starting with an uppercase letter (same goes for the plugin name)! That will save you lots of possible trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mention your plugin name within `$routes->connect`

```
Router::scope('/myFirstPlugin/index', function (RouteBuilder $routes){  
    $routes->connect('/', ['plugin' => 'myFirstPlugin','controller' => 'test', 'action' => 'index']);
});
```

Comment: There's also a method dedicated for plugin routes, ie `Router::plugin()` **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#plugin-routing**